# Spring Boot properties list of multiple datasources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have requirement where I need to specify list of datasources (no fix length) like below in application.properties.

```
#data source 1
tools.datasource[0].url=jdbc:sqlserver://databaseurlOne;databaseName=dbname
tools.datasource[0].username=databaseUser1
tools.datasource[0].password=databasePassword1
tools.datasource[0].driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

#data source 2
tools.datasource[0].url=jdbc:sqlserver://databaseurlTwo;databaseName=dbname
tools.datasource[0].username=databaseUser2
tools.datasource[0].password=databasePassword2
tools.datasource[0].driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

I am trying to read the datasource config like below in code -

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "tools.datasource")
public class MultipleDataSource {

     private List<DataSource> datasources;

     public List<DataSource> getDatasources() {
         return datasources;
    }
}
```

And then I autowire them in my SpringBatch config class like below but it throws NPE when I tried to access my datasource list -

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {



    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired 
    public MultipleDataSource dataSourceConfig;

    public ItemReader<Project> reader(DataSource datasource) {

        dataSourceConfig.getDatasources().forEach(System.out::println);

        JdbcCursorItemReader<Item> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<Item>();
         ......

        return reader;      


     }

}
```

I started using Spring very recently. Any pointer in right direction will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear, but it seems that you defined two identical datasources...

Comment: In above example I defined identical databases (fixing to make it look like diff databases). But actual use case is that there can be N no of databases specified in properties file and I m trying to figure out how to read all of them.

Comment: https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7 . this will help you

Comment: In that example, the # of datasources are known before hand.(ie foo.datasource and bar.datasource). In  my use case, the # of datasouces is not known until run time. So I can not use prefix like foo.datasource and bar.datasouce.